# PyInstaller gives the same encoding error

Tags: python, encoding, pyinstaller

When I am trying to run the command `pyinstaller myscript.py` I get the following error whatever my script contains, I tried with a script with a single line of code like `x=1` or `print('Hello')`. Everything gives the same error.

> 139 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.3.1 139 INFO: Python: 3.6.4 140 INFO:
>   Platform: Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0 Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "c:\anaconda3\envs\py\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in
>   _run_module_as_main
>       "**main**", mod_spec)   File "c:\anaconda3\envs\py\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
>       exec(code, run_globals)   File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\py\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe__main__.py", line 9, in
>      File
>   "c:\anaconda3\envs\py\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller__main__.py", line
>   92, in run
>       spec_file = run_makespec(**vars(args))   File "c:\anaconda3\envs\py\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller__main__.py", line
>   39, in run_makespec
>       spec_file = PyInstaller.building.makespec.main(filenames, **opts)   File
>   "c:\anaconda3\envs\py\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\makespec.py",
>   line 385, in main
>       specfile.write(onedirtmplt % d)   File "c:\anaconda3\envs\py\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
>       return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0] UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in
>   position 127-137: character maps to  < undefined >

Answer (score 0):

The path of the script contained some Non English characters.